# How to add a json element in every write action to MongoDb using C# SDK?

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am currently using C# MongoDB SDK to write my entity to the collection. However, there is a need to write a JSON element during every "write" to the json document. Is there a way to achieve this?

Example: If my entity has 3 properties A,B,C, on every write of this entity object to the MongoDb, I want a 4th element called "default" to be appended and then be sent to the MongoDb.

So, the final document will be A,B,C, default.

Answer (score 0):

There is no generic way to do this in the C# driver, and it's most likely due to the complexity of all the different ways to perform a write.

The simplest way would be to just have your class have read-only internal properties and map these within the Bson Class Map.

```cs
class MyObject
{
    public ObjectId Id { get; set; }
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }

    internal string @default { get; } = "Some-Value";
}

BsonClassMap.RegisterClassMap<MyObject>(map =>
{
    map.AutoMap();
    map.MapMember(x => x.@default);
});

var client = new MongoClient();

var database = client.GetDatabase("test");

var collection = database.GetCollection<MyObject>("myObjects");

collection.InsertOne(new MyObject
{
    A = "1",
    B = "2",
    C = "3"
});
```

Running the following will result in the following document being created.

```
> db.myObjects.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5e94cdb60e844938a8ae23a1"), "A" : "1", "B" : "2", "C" : "3", "default" : "Some-Value" }
```

However, if you do an update you'll have to specify to set this new "default" property too.

```cs
collection.UpdateOne(x => x.A == "1", Builders<MyObject>.Update.Set(x => x.B, "10").Set(x => x.@default, "stuff"));
```